# flux query very slow in compare to InfluxQL (10x slower)

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python, influxql, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

I'm upgrading form influx1.x to influx2.x (updating queries from influxQL to Flux syntax).
For very simple queries, performance drops dramatically when I try to query more than 500,000 points and I'm not sure if there's anything I can do to improve my queries to get better performance

**InfluxQL:**

```
select last("y") AS "y" from "mydata".autogen."profile" 
WHERE time >= '2019-01-01T00:00:00Z' and time <= '2019-01-07T23:59:59Z' 
GROUP BY time(1s) FILL(none)
```

**Flux:**

```
data=from(bucket: "mydata")
|> range(start: 2019-01-01T00:00:00Z, stop: 2019-01-07T23:59:59Z)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "profile")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._field=="y")
|> aggregateWindow(every: 1s, fn: last, createEmpty: false)
|> yield()
```

any advice?

Answer (score 2):

You could try rebuilding the time series index with the command below:

```
influxd inspect build-tsi
```

See more details [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.2/reference/cli/influxd/inspect/build-tsi/).

The reason behind this is while you are upgrading, the meta and data are migrated but not the indices. So "InfluxDB must build a new time series index (TSI). Depending on the volume of data present, this may take some time." according to the [guide.](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.2/upgrade/v1-to-v2/automatic-upgrade/)

Comment: I my case that didn't help unfortunately

Comment: @darkmath did you find any remedy for this?

Comment: @Anish No, unfortunately not.

Comment: @DarkMath, could you try turn on the profiler and see the detailed report according to these two docs ( https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/profiler/  and https://dganais.medium.com/tl-dr-influxdb-tech-tips-optimizing-flux-performance-in-influxdb-cloud-21de08fc50c9 )?